# Does the series converge? If so, find the sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1+2^n}{3^n}$$

I think it can be shown to converge because $r=\frac23<1$. But I can't seem to get the correct sum, which is $\frac53$.

Comment: What is $r$? Try to make your question self contained!

Comment: Splitting it into the sum of two geometric series?

Answer (score 6):

$$ \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1+2^n}{3^n} = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \left(\dfrac  1{3}\right)^n + \sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$

Find the sum in each case (indeed, both sums converge), then add the two sums. In the first sum, you have $r = \dfrac 13$, and in the second case, you have $r = \dfrac 23$, knowing for each $r$, since $0\lt r\lt 1$, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$$

Indeed, the sum totals $\dfrac 32 + 3 = \dfrac 92 \neq \dfrac 53$

Answer (score 5):

HINT: $$\frac{1+2^n}{3^n}=\left(\frac13\right)^n+\left(\frac23\right)^n$$

And the correct sum is not $\dfrac53$ (so it’s possible that you’ve actually done it right and simply don’t realize it).

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$
\frac{1+2^n}{3^n}=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n
$$